# Right after booting from USB and after selecting 'install ubuntu' option I get this error

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, windows-10

Right after booting from USB and after selecting 'install ubuntu' option I get this error. I have disabled secure boot in the UEFI settings as well.

[image: error]

Comment: Please, provide further details about the machine, OS, etc. you are using, so others will be able to pin down the problem further.